# Why can't I chat?

Tags: support, user-accounts, chat

I earned the cred, but for some reason when I enter the chat rooms, I receive a ribbon message indicating that I'm not allowed to participate. I'm thinking my English Language & Usage account is not properly linked with my main Stack Exchange account.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your ELU account is indeed not properly associated with your other ones. (See e.g. your [accounts tab on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775356/codelegant?tab=accounts).) Try clearing all associations and re-associating again. (Note that auto-association only works if you use the same OpenID on all sites. Otherwise, use the "add openid" link in your user profile.)

Comment: After logging out, destroying my credentials, and deleting my cookies, the issue seems to be resolved. Thank you.